# which version of python is compatible with PyEnchant?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyenchant

I've been trying to install PyEnchant using conda. I've tried in python 3.5, .6, .7, .8, .9 and .10 but I'm getting the same notification everytime:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions.

Does anyone knows how to proceed?

Comment: Try installing it using pip or `conda install --channel=conda-forge pyenchant`. Based on https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/install.html it is python 3.7 and above compatible.

Comment: PyEnchant is a Python binding to Enchant. On non-Windows systems you need to install Enchant itself first, on Windows the library is pre-built.